How do I define a timer in code composer studio in gpiointerrupt.c
I need to create a state machine to blink "SOS" code with the LED lights. Using the Timer.h file reference from ti.com, I tried to implement this,..
Timer_Handle    handle;
Timer_Params    params;
Timer_Params_init(&params);
params.periodUnits = Timer_PERIOD_HZ;
params.period = 1000;
params.timerMode  = Timer_CONTINUOUS_CALLBACK;
params.timerCallback = UserCallbackFunction;
handle = Timer_open(Board_TIMER0, &params);
if (handle == NULL) {
    // Timer_open() failed
    while (1);
}
status = Timer_start(handle);
if (status == Timer_STATUS_ERROR) {
    //Timer_start() failed
    while (1);
}
sleep(10000);
Timer_stop(handle);

My full code to blink an SOS message:
/*
 *  ======== gpiointerrupt.c ========
 */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>


/* Driver Header files */
#include <ti/drivers/GPIO.h>
#include <ti/drivers/Timer.h>

/* Driver configuration */
#include "ti_drivers_config.h"




enum MESSAGES {SOS, OK} CURRENT_MESSAGE, BUTTON_PRESS;

enum LED {RED_LED, LED_OFF, GREEN_LED} LED_STATE;

enum LED sos[] = {
    // Print "S"
    RED_LED, LED_OFF,
    RED_LED, LED_OFF,
    RED_LED, LED_OFF, RED_LED, LED_OFF,

    // Print "O"
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF,
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF,
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF,

    // Print "S"
    RED_LED, LED_OFF,
    RED_LED, LED_OFF,
    RED_LED, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF
};

enum LED ok[] = {
    //Print "O"
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF,
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF,
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF,

    // Print "K"
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, LED_OFF,
    RED_LED, LED_OFF,
    GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED, GREEN_LED,
    LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF, LED_OFF

};

unsigned int mCounter = 0;

void setMorseCodeLEDs() {
    switch (LED_STATE) {
        case RED_LED:
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_ON);
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_1, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);
            break;
        case GREEN_LED:
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_1, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_ON);
            break;
        case LED_OFF:
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);
            GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_1, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}
/*
 *  ======== gpioButtonPress ========
 *  Callback function for the GPIO interrupt on CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0 and                    *  CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1.
 *
 */
void gpioButtonPress(uint_least8_t index)
{
    switch(BUTTON_PRESS) {
        case SOS:
            BUTTON_PRESS = OK;
            break;
        case OK:
            BUTTON_PRESS = SOS;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
/*
 *  ======== timerCallback ========
 *  Callback function for the timer interrupt
 */
void timerCallback(Timer_Handle myHandle, int_fast16_t status) {
    switch (CURRENT_MESSAGE) {
        case SOS:
            LED_STATE = sos[mCounter];
            setMorseCodeLEDs();
            mCounter++;

            if (mCounter == (sizeof(sos)/sizeof(sos[0]))) {
                CURRENT_MESSAGE = BUTTON_PRESS;
                mCounter = 0;
            }   
            break;
        case OK:
            LED_STATE = ok[mCounter];

            setMorseCodeLEDs();
            mCounter++;

            if (mCounter == (sizeof(ok)/sizeof(ok[0]))) {
                CURRENT_MESSAGE = BUTTON_PRESS;
                mCounter = 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    
    }
}

/*
 *  ======== initTimer ========
 *
 * Initiate the timer interrupt function
 */
void initTimer(void)
{
    Timer_Handle timer0;
    Timer_Params params;
    Timer_init();
    Timer_Params_init(&params);
    params.period = 500000;
    params.periodUnits = Timer_PERIOD_US;
    params.timerMode = Timer_CONTINUOUS_CALLBACK;
    params.timerCallback = timerCallback;
    timer0 = Timer_open(CONFIG_TIMER_0, &params);
    if (timer0 == NULL) {
    /* Failed to initialized timer */
    while (1) {}
    }
    if (Timer_start(timer0) == Timer_STATUS_ERROR) {
    /* Failed to start timer */
    while (1) {}
    }
}

/*
 *  ======== mainThread ========
 */
void *mainThread(void *arg0)
{
    /* Call driver init functions */
    GPIO_init();
    /* Call the timer*/
    initTimer();

    /* Configure the LED and button pins */
    GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, GPIO_CFG_OUT_STD | GPIO_CFG_OUT_LOW);
    GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_1, GPIO_CFG_OUT_STD | GPIO_CFG_OUT_LOW);
    GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0, GPIO_CFG_IN_PU | GPIO_CFG_IN_INT_FALLING);

    /* Start with both LEDs off */
    GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_0, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);
    GPIO_write(CONFIG_GPIO_LED_1, CONFIG_GPIO_LED_OFF);

    /* Install Button callback */
    GPIO_setCallback(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0, gpioButtonPress);

    /* Set initial states*/
    BUTTON_PRESS = SOS;
    CURRENT_MESSAGE = BUTTON_PRESS;

    /* Enable interrupts */
    GPIO_enableInt(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0);

    /*
     *  If more than one input pin is available for your device, interrupts
     *  will be enabled on CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON1.
     */
    if (CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_0 != CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1)
    {
        /* Configure BUTTON1 pin */
        GPIO_setConfig(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1, GPIO_CFG_IN_PU | GPIO_CFG_IN_INT_FALLING);

        /* Install Button callback */
        GPIO_setCallback(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1, gpioButtonPress);
        GPIO_enableInt(CONFIG_GPIO_BUTTON_1);
    }

    return (NULL);
}

Timer_Handle and Timer_Params are both red and I get this error when I try to build,

Errors(3 items)
#20 identifier "Timer_Handle0" is undefined
gmake: ***[gpiointerrupt.obj] Error 1
gmake: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.

I'm not familiar with TI but the error looks like related about include path. May be this can helps your issue How to add an include directory in CCS?
